# Check if a string is of a string pattern

Tags: c#

I have the following string pattern:

```
const string STRING_PATTERN = "Hello {0}";
```

How can I check a string is of the above string pattern?

For example:

string "Hello World" is of the above string pattern

string "abc" is not of the above string pattern.

Best

Comment: Can you write a simple sample code?

Comment: Would `str.StartsWith("Hello ")` be enough? If not, what exactly do you need?

Comment: If I use StartsWith, it will not work correctly with the following pattern "Hello {0}, Welcome to ABC"

Comment: @e1011892: You really need to flesh out your requirements for this expression first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^Hello .+$")
```

Or as @usr suggested:

```
myString.StartsWith("Hello ")
```

Comment: Assuming that I have an unknown string pattern, how can I check a string is of this pattern?

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(myString, pattern)` if `pattern` is a regular expression. If you have a pattern in your format, you can transform it into a regular expression first, or write your own parser.

Comment: I am new with regular expression, can you write a sample code which transform the following pattern "Hello {0}" ({0} is a number) into a regular expression?

Comment: @e1011892: Look up online regular expression builders.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="Hello World";

      string re1="(Hello)"; // Word 1
      string re2=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
      string re3="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 2

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String word1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String word2=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+word2.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```